# Drupal 7 Views Contextual Links edit Nodes and Fields

Tags: drupal, view, field, hyperlink, edit

I created some Views with Drupal 7 and also installed the module Contextual Links.
It helps me to edit Views and Blocks. But for non-admin users like Editors etc. it would be great to even edit Nodes or Fields with Contextual Links.

So I hover a Field there should appear a Edit Link.

I couldn't find any detailed settings for Contextual Links.

Please tell me how to set this up.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be of some use: http://realize.be/contextual-links-backport-more-or-less